# How to override MUIv4 class globally in JSS for nested themes?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

TL;DR: Scroll to EDIT2

MUIv4 created the following classes for me from my nested theming:

```html
<label class="MuiFormLabel-root-121 
MuiInputLabel-root-113 
MuiInputLabel-formControl-115 
MuiInputLabel-animated-118 
MuiInputLabel-shrink-117 
MuiInputLabel-marginDense-116 
MuiInputLabel-outlined-120 
Mui-disabled 
Mui-disabled 
MuiFormLabel-filled-123" 

data-shrink="true">Email</label>
```

Now I'm interested into changing the following class:

```css
.MuiInputLabel-outlined-120.MuiInputLabel-shrink-117 {
    transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);
}
```

therefore I have a theming file
[duplicates just have the purpose to show what I tried]:

```js
createTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiInputLabel: {
        outlined: {
          color: red[500],
          backgroundColor:purple[600],
          MuiInputLabel: {
            shrink: {
              transform: "translate(0px, -15px) scale(0.75) !important",
            }
          },
          "&.MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
            transform: "translate(0px, -15px) scale(0.75) !important",
          },
          "&[class*='MuiInputLabel-shrink']":{
            transform: "translate(0px, -15px) scale(0.75) !important",
          },
        }
      },
    },
  })
```

But none of the rules work?
What am I doing wrong?
How can I see the generated classNames from createTheme?

EDIT -
I was able to achieve the wanted effect with a CSS Wrapper:

```
const MUIWrapper = styled.div`
[class*="MuiInputLabel-outlined"][class*="MuiInputLabel-shrink"] {
    transform: translate(0px, -15px) scale(0.75);
}
  }
`
```

But actually I didn't wanted to implemented it this way

EDIT 2:
As pointed out by `@hotcakedev` it is possible with:

```js
createTheme({
    overrides: {
      ...
      MuiFormLabel: {
        outlined: {
          '.MuiInputLabel-shrink*': { // or '&.MuiInputLabel-shrink*'
            transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);
          }
        },
      }
    },
  })
```

but I still wonder why there is no possibility to write it like this:

```js
createTheme({
    overrides: {
      ...
      MuiFormLabel: {
        outlined: {
          MuiInputLabel: { 
            shrink: {
              transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);
            }
          }
        },
      }
    },
  })
```

This would be what I would wish to write, since it is clear and easy readable!

Comment: What version of MUI do you use, 4 or 5?

Comment: @hotcakedev thank you for the hint. I added the version information as well as an EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you built your theme like that (has duplicated `MuiInputLabel`).

Please make sure the theme structure has no duplicated overriding components.

```
  createTheme({
    overrides: {
      ...
      MuiFormLabel: {
        outlined: {
          ...
        },
        shrink: {
          ...
        }
      }
    },
  })
```

If you want to style the same component inside a specific component, you could use `&` and other css tricks in the nested theme structure.

```
  createTheme({
    overrides: {
      ...
      MuiFormLabel: {
        outlined: {
          '.MuiInputLabel-shrink*': { // or '&.MuiInputLabel-shrink*'
            transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);
          }
        },
      }
    },
  })
```

Otherwise, you could build your own global styles.

```
// GlobalStyles.js
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => createStyles({
  '@global': {
    '*': {
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
    },
    body: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    '#root': {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }
    ...
    '.some-class': {
      '.MuiInputLabel-shrink*': { // or '&.MuiInputLabel-shrink*'
        transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);
      }
    }
  }
}));

const GlobalStyles = () => {
  useStyles();

  return null;
};

export default GlobalStyles;

// App.js

...
import GlobalStyles from './GlobalStyles.js';

const App = () => {
  return (
    ...
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyles />
      ...
    </Router>
    ...
  )
};
```

Comment: I put duplicated overrides there to show all the rules I tried! Is there no JSS version instead of: `'.MuiInputLabel-shrink*'` or `'&.MuiInputLabel-shrink*'`. I would like to stay with the `<MuiElement>: {<sub>: {}}`-notation also for class combinations.

Comment: @user2853437 Please check my updates.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I edited my answer again and since I think there is no better way I will take your answer. thank you!